# No popover window in bootstrap tour

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I just add bootstrap-tour.min.js under bootstrap.js and bootstrap-tour.min.css under bootstrap.min.css. It's seems to work because target area is selected and all background faded. But where is tour control?

```
var tour = new Tour({
  steps: [
  {
    element: ".one",
    title: "Welcome",
    content: "Welcome to our app, take this tour to be familirized with it."
  },
      {
    element: ".two",
    title: "This Image",
    content: "In this application we generate random placeholder images for any case."
  }  
],
  backdrop: true,
  storage: false
});

tour.init();
tour.start();
```

See it at:
http://livespot.pl/bootstrap-tour-problem/

Comment: You have an error in console. I believe it is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the Bootstrap tour script include, add the standalone or non-standalone version of the tour javascript and put the include in the head of the page.

```
<script src="bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js"></script>
```